# Manipulate return statement for a string or an array with html segments

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

I would like to manipulate the return statement from **Template.info.helpers** in the way that it will display **iterate** like:

0
1
...

How to do this? Maybe using jquery. Maybe another solution (I treid it with **`iterate.split("</a></div>");`**), thought it´s easier if I have an array. I tried a little but there was no satisfactory result. Help please.

> .js

```
Template.info.helpers({
    info() {
        var iterate ="";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            iterate += "<div class='row'><a href=" + i + ">" + i + "</a></div>";
        }
        return iterate;
    }
)};
```

> .html

```
<template name="info">
    <a href="{{pathFor route='info'}}">Home</a>
    </br>
    <a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello</a>
    <p>{{info}}</p> 
    <!-- 
    Gives raw text and returns it as a string -> WORKS NOT FINE:
    <div class='row'><a href=0>0</a></div><div class='row'><a href=1>1</a></div> ... and so on
    -->
</template>
```

Comment: Use theee { like {{{info}}}

Comment: Read: http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Rendering-raw-HTML

Comment: That's it... Thanks very much.